# Overflow with product of ints

Tags: c, overflow

In the code below, the value of prod is not 9,000,000; it gets a garbage value.  Why do we need num1 and num2 to be of type long?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num1 = 3000, num2 = 3000;
    long int prod = num1 * num2;
    printf("%ld\n", prod);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try casting them to long before multiplying.

Comment: It comes out to the 9000000 for me.  Are you verifying in a debugger or from the output?

Comment: @linuxuser: Want to bet that your `int` is wider than his?

Comment: I renamed the question, as these are products, not sums.

Comment: `int` isn't just `long` enough.

Comment: @fahad: 1985 called. It wants its compiler back.

Comment: BTW, mine is wider and longer than his! ;-)

Comment: @R:Its Turbo C compiler,+1 for that

Comment: @Roger:Why was there a need of a newline in my printf()?

Comment: @fahad: It's conventional to not exit after printing a partial line and I just included it automatically when reformatting the code, since I was already editing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When num1*num2 is computed, it is stored in an intermediate variable that is of the same type (i.e., an int), which comes up as garbage because it's not big enough. Then, the intermediate variable is stored in a long int, but the computed answer was already turned into garbage.

The solution is to cast one of the arguments of the multiplication.

```
long int prod = (long int)num1 * num2;
```

This way, the intermediate computation will use the bigger of the two types, and store it temporarily as a long int.

Comment: Note: overflow (and underflow) with ints causes **Undefined Behaviour**. Avoid at all costs: use `unsigned ints` (no UB, but possible wrong results) or check for overflow **before** it happens.

Comment: @pmg: Well, an unsigned int will double the range over a signed one, but that's not always going to prevent an overflow. Is overflowing an unsigned int "defined"?

Comment: @Steven: when `unsigned ints` "overflow" they do not cause UB; they wrap around to 0 (they operate `MOD(UINT_MAX + 1)`).

Comment: People around here get maybe a little too breathless about UB.  `#include <unistd.h>` (or `#include <windows.h>`, pick yer poison) is just as much UB as signed integer overflow.  What matters when you get down to it, is how likely the compiler is to make demons fly out of your nose in any given *case* of UB (much more so for signed integer overflow than for platform-specific header files, at least with modern compilers).

Comment: @Zack: Not really - what matters is what implementations you want to be portable to.  With `#include <windows.h>`, it's reasonably obvious - but relying on a particular behaviour for signed integer overflow is a lot more subtle.

Comment: The undefinedness of signed overflow is not just some theoretical matter or weirdness of legacy non-twos-complement machines. Modern gcc uses the fact that signed overflow is UB to optimize better - it assumes the coder has ensured as a precondition that any signed values used in arithmetic cannot result in overflow.

Comment: @Roger: No, I know whereof I speak.  If you `#include` a header which you did not write, which is not one of the standard headers listed in section 7.1.2, and which does not trip the constraint violation at the beginning of 6.10.2 (i.e. it *does* "identify a file that the implementation can process"), the behavior is undefined.  How could it be otherwise?  The contents of a platform-specific header are *not defined* by the C standard.

Comment: @Zack: The standard, to my knowledge, does not distinguish between "3rd party" headers (such as unistd.h, sqlite.h, readline.h, ...) and headers you "personally" wrote.  Is there a clause I've missed?

Comment: @pmg: I'd call that a well-defined overflow. The reason the signed version is undefined is simply that the C standard doesn't define how negative numbers are stored. These days, it's almost always two's complement, but it could be one's complement or any other viable scheme.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is such a clause but I'm not finding it at the moment.  I could argue that it falls under the "by the omission of any explicit definition of behavior" language in 4p2 but that feels like a cop-out.  Sorry I can't be more conclusive.

Comment: @pmg: One hazard with built-in headers is that there's no guarantee of the relative size between a UInt32 and an 'int'.  If 'int' is 33-64 bits, the product of two UInt32's could yield undefined behavior.  I don't know of anything smaller than UInt64 to which they could safely be cast, and casting to UInt64 to ensure a correct UInt32 result seems really icky.